# What are the typical emissions of Jupiter's Aurorae?

Tags: jupiter, aurora, electromagnetic-spectrum

I'm looking for some solid measurements of the full range of emissions from the Aurorae on Jupiter. I've found partial [sets of data](http://www.bu.edu/csp/uv/cp-aeronomy/Bhardwaj_Gladstone_RG_2000.pdf) in the past which are most easily summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Jupiter#Aurorae). As you can see, this set of data is missing several ranges of emissions. The missing ranges I'm most interested in are from .18μm-.385μm, and 1μm-3μm. Graphs are greatly appreciated so I can integrate certain wavelengths myself, as well as different data sets which separate the power of emissions into more specific categories such as UVA/UVB/UVC.

The holy grail of answering this question would be a graph similar to a black body radiation graph with the x-axis being wavelengths in μm and the Y axis being Spectral Radiance as seen here:

[image: Black Body radiation]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black_body.svg)

Comment: You can edit the question however you see fit. The link to images was not for my benefit, but the benefit of anyone reading the question in the future especially laymen like myself. I'm not regular on stackexchange so whatever is most pleasing to you while getting the information across is just fine.

Comment: Different but related (and some potentially helpful links to sources): [Have auroras on Titan been observed yet?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40894/7982) and [Why is Ganymede's aurora only visible in ultraviolet while Earth's is bright green and red?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34722/7982) and since your spectral range extends to almost-visible UV [Could Ganymede's aurora be seen with the naked eye?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29064/7982)